# How to display Date?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following code to display the date in the front-end screen:

```
<h4> Date :
        <script language="JavaScript">
            date=Date()
            document.write(date)
        </script>
</h4>
```

Here `h4` is the tag in CSS. 
Here is the code for `h4` in CSS file:

It is displaying the date in local machine. But when I deployed the project to the server machine it is not working.

Comment: @Raj..You mean you want to display date of server using javascript?

Comment: @Tushar .. Yes , I want to display server time in front end screen using java script

Comment: What exactly is your problem? What do you mean by 'it is not working?'  If you want to display the time by the server machine, you will have to use a different (server-side) language, such as PHP, because JavaScript is a client-side language. IF you still insist on using javaScript you will have to have a PHP file or something that returns the time on the server, and then get that using JavaScript (AJAX).

Comment: @Raj, I don't understand why you would do that using javascript. Just display the server time in whatever template you use to generate that h4. In erb, for example, that would be something like "<h4>Date: <%= Time.now %></h4>". Obviously, it will be different depending on what framework you are using on the server. In any case, I don't see why you'd do this with javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript runs on the client machine (on the browser). `new Date()` in javascript gives the date from the client's machine.

To get the date from the server side, you need to pass the date from the server to the client. How you do this depends on the server side technology.

In JSP it would be something like:

```
<h4> Date : <%= new java.util.Date()%> </h4>
```

And in PHP:

```
<h4><?php echo date("d-m-Y"); ?> </h4>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But I am using Servlets and home page is html from html action I am calling this servlet .. Now I want to display the time in the home page it self

Comment: If you need the date in the home page, then the home page should be a `jsp`. Change the html to a jsp (Mostly just changing the extension and the related mappings. You can also redirect from your HTML to the jsp) and add the code in the answer `<%...%>` to get the date. You may also want to use [SimpleDateformat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format the date